# Visual Studio 2012 - No "Attach to process" option in Debug menu

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I have no option in my Debug tab for Attach To Process.

VS Professional 2012
V 11 Update 3

[image]

Comment: Or in this case, `TOOLS`.  Those all-caps menus were likely the first thing I disabled. :-)

Comment: wow... words can not express my embarrassment. Thank you both though :)

Comment: should i just delete this thread? not sure of the proper action on a useless question. lol